# Test org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryResults.asModel(result)

Tags: testing, rdf4j

What object can I pass to QueryResults.asModel() so when I test a method that runs the line:

final var model = QueryResults.asModel(result);

result has at least one Statement and asModel finishes correctly and returns what I set in the test?

when(queryResults.asModel(graphQueryResult)).thenReturn(model);

Answer (score 0):

Would this example help?

```java
ValueFactory vf = SimpleValueFactory.getInstance();
Statement s = vf.createStatement(vf.createIRI("htp://example.org/type"), RDF.TYPE, OWL.CLASS);
CloseableIteration it = new IteratingGraphQueryResult(Collections.emptyMap(), List.of(s));
Model m = QueryResults.asModel(it);
assertEquals(new LinkedHashModel(List.of(s)), m);
```

Of course, it is possible to mock the result of `QueryResults.asModel`, but as it is a third-party code, it is generally advised to use it rather than mocking it.

*Note that some of the types in the example are deprecated as of RDF4J 4.1.0, so they may not exist in the upcoming 5.0.0 release of RDF4J.*